# Bold vectors in Metropolis beamer theme

Tags: beamer, overleaf, vector, beamer-metropolis

On overleaf, is there a way to set the vectors in the Metropolis beamer theme in bold italics? All the usual ways (e.g. renewing the command as a '\boldsymbol{{#1}}') do not seem to work. It actually turns them simply into bold face, but not in italics.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that replicates your current behaviour? It should start with `\documentclass{beamer}` and end with `\end{document}` and just include the necessary essentials (like the equation above) so we can copy-and-paste-and-compile it and see exactly what you're seeing. Include the stuff that didn't work, so we have a better handle on things. Can you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the following works fine.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
%\usefonttheme{serif}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      $x~\vec{x}$
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you can provide a MWE (minimum working example), we would probably be able to tell you more.

Or do you want to have 'more fancy' letters like in the default article font? Then uncomment the `\usefonttheme{serif}`-line in the preamble.

[image: Without \usefonttheme{serif}]
[image: With \usefonttheme{serif}]

Comment: Hi, thanks. However, I'm using overleaf and when I'm doing it, it gives something like (see above)

Comment: even after re-copying and pasting what you have and uncommenting the \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I'm afraid I can not help you as I am not familiar with overleaf. I'd recommend you to add this information to your question.